# How to prevent (or at least automatically fix) `avahi-daemon: running [ubuntu_comp_hostname.local]` getting replaced with version with `-2` appended?

Tags: networking, 20.04, ssh, services, avahi

I have this problem where this:
#=> `avahi-daemon: running [ubuntu_comp_hostname.local]`
keeps getting itself replaced with a version with a `-2` appended:
#=> `avahi-daemon: running [ubuntu_comp_hostname-2.local]`

(
I find that from:
> `ps -eo cmd | grep avahi`
which other than that (and the grep itself) turns up just:
#=> `avahi-daemon: chroot helper`
)

---

I've been fixing the problem by just running:
> `sudo service avahi-daemon restart`
but it's just annoying whenever I try to run some shell function that involves ssh,
and it just hangs for a while before finally going:
#=> `ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu_comp_hostname.local: Name or service not known`

---

(This is just a personal laptop, on a home network with one of those standard-issue issue modem-router setups from the local ISP company.)

---

I'm sadly pretty ignorant (on this subject in particular and in general),
but it seems reasonable to guess that:

- avahi is crashing or restarting or something
- and then it tries to start again with plain `[ubuntu_comp_hostname.local]`,
  but that's still hanging around in a defunct state or something
  (as a process on the computer? or in some cache somewhere else on the network? or...?)
  so it automatically appends a `-2` to the end of the actual hostname

Something like that, right?

---

I'm not sure exactly when it happens. All I can say is:

- it doesn't happen *every* time the computer wakes up from sleep
- it *may* happen at times *other than* when the computer has just woken up from sleep

---

So... **how can I prevent this from happening?**
(Or failing that, get it to automatically fix itself when it *does* happen??)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on a Raspberry Pi.  Until a better solution comes along, Ive added a crontab entry to run this script every day.

```
#!/bin/bash

writelog()
{
echo $(date) >> /home/pi/avahirestart.log
}
aname=$(avahi-resolve -a $(hostname -I|cut -d' ' -f1)|cut -f2)
if [[ "$aname" = *"-2"* ]];then
sudo service avahi-daemon restart
writelog
fi
if [[ "$aname" = *"-3"* ]];then
sudo service avahi-daemon restart
writelog
fi
```